# Identifying the candidate duplication in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, search, uniqueidentifier, fragment-identifier

I have user name, dob, emailID, phone no etc in my db, each time a new entry is made i have to identify that user already exists in my db or not. By searching whole database, What keys will identify anyone uniquely? How can I do it?
I have to do it on large database, so how can i do it efficiently.

Comment: You have to choose for yourself what attributes have to be unique. Be careful that 2 people with the same name can exist. A lot of people take the date of birth into account too, but even then duplicates exist. Usually the government provides with unique numbers, such as Social Security Number or Identification Number, but it's not always legal to ask for those. Decide for yourself...

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE (
`id` ,
`emailID`
);
```